# How to make canvas graph responsive?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I made this graph using canvas. However this graph is not responsive and when I tried to make it responsive by drawing according to the new size The old lines remained on the screen along with the new lines. how can I resize each line without drawing them again and again?

---

1. ```js
   function drawShape(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l) {
       var canvas = document.getElementById('linegraph1');
       var value = new Array(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l);
       var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
       for (i = 1; i < 13; i++) {
           {
               ctx.beginPath();
               ctx.lineWidth = 9;
               ctx.lineCap = 'round';
               ctx.strokeStyle = '#FFFFFF';
               ctx.moveTo(7 + i * 30, 50);
               ctx.lineTo(7 + i * 30, 150);
               ctx.stroke();
           }
           {
               ctx.beginPath();
               ctx.lineWidth = 9;
               ctx.lineCap = 'round';
               ctx.strokeStyle = '#EFF2FB';
               ctx.moveTo(7 + i * 30, 50);
               ctx.lineTo(7 + i * 30, 150);
               ctx.stroke();
           }
           ctx.lineWidth = 9;
           ctx.beginPath();
           ctx.moveTo(7 + i * 30, 150);
           if (value[i - 1] > 100) {
               var buffer = 50;
           } else {
               var buffer = 150 - value[i - 1];
           }
           ctx.lineTo(7 + i * 30, buffer);
           if (value[i - 1] > 80) {
               ctx.strokeStyle = '#B60114';
           } else {
               ctx.strokeStyle = '#0093CF';
           }
           ctx.lineCap = 'round';
           ctx.lineCap = 'round';
           ctx.font = "15px Arial";
           ctx.fillText(value[i - 1], 1 + i * 30, 180);
           ctx.stroke();
       }
       ctx.beginPath();
       ctx.font = "15px Arial";
       ctx.fillText("0", 400, 150);
       ctx.fillText("25", 400, 105);
       ctx.fillText("50", 400, 60);
       ctx.fillText("mb", 400, 180);
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <div>
       <canvas id="linegraph1" width="450" height="200" style="border:1px solid grey; border-radius: 10px;">
   </div>
   <button onclick="drawShape(10, 20, 80, 45, 55, 88, 74, 41, 45, 12, 21, 12)">Draw Graph</button>
   ```

---

Comment: You can't..... canvas is just like image.... you have to destroy old one while creating the new

Comment: create a virtual `canvas` copy the original  canvas's content to it (with `drawImage()`) then you should calculate the scale difference by percentage, like dividing new width and height with the previous width and height, so after a quick `clearRect()`, you can `scale()` your context, then copy the content of the virtual canvas to your original one

Comment: I like SVG for more responsive stuff.  https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use css on the canvas element:

```js
function drawShape(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l) {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('linegraph1');
  var value = new Array(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l);
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  //Wipe canvas between draws
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  for (i = 1; i < 13; i++) {
    {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.lineWidth = 90;
      ctx.lineCap = 'round';
      ctx.strokeStyle = '#FFFFFF';
      ctx.moveTo(7 + i * 300, 500);
      ctx.lineTo(7 + i * 300, 1500);
      ctx.stroke();
    } {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.lineWidth = 90;
      ctx.lineCap = 'round';
      ctx.strokeStyle = '#EFF2FB';
      ctx.moveTo(7 + i * 300, 500);
      ctx.lineTo(7 + i * 300, 1500);
      ctx.stroke();
    }
    ctx.lineWidth = 90;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(7 + i * 300, 1500);
    if (value[i - 1] > 100) {
      var buffer = 50;
    } else {
      var buffer = 150 - value[i - 1];
    }
    ctx.lineTo(7 + i * 300, buffer);
    if (value[i - 1] > 80) {
      ctx.strokeStyle = '#B60114';
    } else {
      ctx.strokeStyle = '#0093CF';
    }
    ctx.lineCap = 'round';
    ctx.lineCap = 'round';
    ctx.font = "150px Arial";
    ctx.fillText(value[i - 1], 1 + i * 300, 1800);
    ctx.stroke();
  }
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.font = "150px Arial";
  ctx.fillText("0", 4000, 1500);
  ctx.fillText("25", 4000, 1050);
  ctx.fillText("50", 4000, 600);
  ctx.fillText("mb", 4000, 1800);
}
```

```css
#linegraph1 {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 10px;
  /* Fit window */
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <canvas id="linegraph1" width="4500" height="2000"></canvas>
</div>
<button onclick="drawShape(10, 20, 80, 45, 55, 88, 74, 41, 45, 12, 21, 12)">Draw Graph</button>
```

**EDIT**

Enlarged the drawn canvas to avoid bad pixelation when stretching.